# Is it a risk if someone knows your Swedish Identity Number?

Tags: sweden

I am concerned that someone received a photo of my Swedish ID along with the SIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swedish personal identity numbers (*personnummer*) are public information, so that part is not a risk.

But a photo of ID is sometimes accepted as if it were evidence of possessing ID by various companies etc, so you may want to ask the issuer of your ID to cancel it and get a new one.